# SQL alchemy not running sprocs despite 'finding them'

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a simple SPROC in a postgres SQL V14 database that does the following:

`CREATE PROCEDURE testSProc() LANGUAGE SQL AS $$ INSERT INTO "activePairs" ("SYMBOL") VALUES ('Hello'); $$;`

I am trying to run this SPROC from SQL alchemy in python using:

`with engine.connect() as connection: connection.execute("CALL testSProc();")`

The connection.execute seems to work fine... except it doesnt actually do anything! I can call the SPROC from the PSQL command line and it runs fine, but no joy from python.

Changing the function name, it kicks an error, taking out parenthesis, kicks an error, trying with SELECT, kicks an error. So its as though its trying to run it, but not.

Sorry I'm a bit new to SQL and python, so if I've missed something obvious in the docs, I apologise!

Any helps appreciated

A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with engine.connect() ...` rolls back when it exits.  You can either commit manually:

```
with engine.connect() as connection:
    connection.execute(sa.text('CALL testSProc()'))
    connection.commit()
```

or use `engine.begin()`, which commits on exit:

```
with engine.begin() as connection:
    connection.execute(sa.text('CALL testSProc()'))
```

Comment: The engine.begin() worked a charm!
For some reason I only have available connection.commit_prepared() in the first example, which needs positional args that I do not know, so does not work.

Why would you want the DB to roll back in the first example?

Comment: You could be executing a `SELECT` for example, so there's no need to commit as no changes are made.